# Cannot compile, Lvalue required, in function main

Tags: c++

I want to compile this, but it gives me error, even i change the quotes, is there any error in header file, please let me know

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>


void main()
{
char st[20];

cin>>st;


cout<<st<<endl;

if (st = 'a')
cout<<"This is a";


if (st = 'b')
cout<<"This is b";

getch();
}
```

Comment: iostream.h is depreciated, use the iostream header instead. Also don't ``#include <conio.h>``, conio is not apart of the C or C++ standard, don't use it (unless you need it, which you don't).

Comment: Also, prefer ``int main()`` over ``void main()``. And also, ``#include <cstdio>`` if you're going to use ``getch()``. If you're learning from a book, I recommend you to get a new one.

Comment: Oh thank you!
After my post I came to know that yeah i must use == instead of =, but i am dont want to edit as below members mention the == case, So i am sure this will help some one after me.

Comment: Yeah, u are right! Can u give me just the name of the book and writer name, i will be happy. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://isocpp.org/get-started has a list of books on it (it's the official site for C++, I recommend exploring that site). For a specific book, I recommend [this](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Principles-Practice-Using-C/dp/0321543726/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1343779600&sr=1-1) one if you are a beginner at programming http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Principles-Practice-Using-C/dp/0321543726/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1343779600&sr=1-1

Comment: @miguel.martin: `getch()` is a Microsoft-specific function declared in `<conio.h>`. `getc()` and `getchar()` are declared in `<cstdio>`.

Comment: Oh thanks you very much! I will read this book, and I am not a beginner (I have experience of many languages) thats why i often get error in syntax lolz. I have learn C language, thats why I also used the C syntax here. But I am sure I will learn cpp also, and one thing I often think Oh I have made a mistake why not I learn CPP before others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (st = 'a')
if (st = 'b')
```

In both the above lines l-value(left value) 'st' point to the beginning of the array and its address cannot be changed. That's why you get the error with l-value in compilation. Change the If conditions with equality(==) operator instead of assignment(=) and dereference st to get the value in the beginning.

```
if (*st == 'a')
if (*st == 'b')
```

Comment: Wah! On the above condition (after changing = to ==) and apply ur suggestion I run it succesfully. Thankd

Comment: Yeah this worked for me, before the other answers, I think this answer really suits my question so i accpted that. Also the other questions are also very helpful and informative

Answer (score 2):

`=` is not for compare,

```
if (st = 'a') 


if (st = 'b')
```

It will try to change `st` and the  result of above compares are always `true`.

Try to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
#include <string>

...

std::string st;

std::cin >> st;

cout<<st<<endl;

if (st == "a")
  cout<<"This is a";


if (st == "b")
  cout<<"This is b";
```

Comment: I checkde on both, still not working as (= is for assignment), still not working, this is simple program but i am really in trouble

Comment: Oh noes! +1 for suggesting string.

Comment: Yes! I am really sorry, u actually help me, but that was by me, that u have lost ur reputation, why ppl just give down vote, why not they just mention of comments, i cannot give vote up as I am new , I am really sorry :(

Comment: "It will change the value of st and the result of compare is always true." The result of the compare will ***not*** be true ***if*** he assigns it (an index, or another variable) to 0. http://ideone.com/eZuPxP

Comment: @miguel.martin: yes, but he is assigning `'a'` or `'b'`, not `0`

Comment: @IslamKhan You can still remove your downvote by pressing the down arrow again, no?

Comment: @MM. Yes, but still. You should give OP a link to std::string documentation and you forgot to mention that he/she has to #include <string>

Comment: @Agentlien Oh but i never give down votes. Just look at my points and reputation I am now at that time unable to voteup or down

Comment: @miguel.martin: Come on, suggesting `#include` is good, but it's not mandatory for obvious things, check `NPE`'s answer for `strcmp`, I commented `#include <string.h>` under his answer.

Comment: @MM. ``#include <string.h>`` is very different to ``#include <string>``. OP seems to be learning, so it's probably not obvious to him

Comment: @miguel.martin: You didn't get my point, I said, check his answer, he doesn't mentioned `#include<string.h>` in his answer too.

Comment: Hy boys! Npw just leave this. Thanks for ur answers and time.

Comment: @miguel.martin and M M. I think you both have a point. It shouldn't always be necessary to state the necessary #include, but if the OP seems inexperienced or uncertain about some basic stuff, that's an indication that it might be necessary in that particular case.

Comment: @Agentlien: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

The following aren't quite right:

```
if (st = 'a')
if (st = 'b')
```

First of all, `=` is assignment rather than comparison. Secondly `'a'` and `'b'` are `char` rather than string literals.

The correct way to write the above is

```
if (strcmp(st, "a") == 0)
if (strcmp(st, "b") == 0)
```

That said, I would encourage you to move away from using C string and use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Thanks! But now it gives this error : Call to undefined function 'strcmp' in function main()

Comment: `#include <string.h>` or `#include <cstring>`

Comment: Ok ok I got it, thanks, this thread now must be closed, as this is solved, thnak you all members

Answer (score 0):

Well, on my line of studying. You are using an assignment operator "="
Import the string.h directive, and use the `strcmp();` function of that library
hope this helps